# How to change active nav color in react js while getting data from an array?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am using array to display nav items in react. I have set classname for all `li` tags. Now I want when I click on a particular item its color should got changed.
I have tried with usestate also but not able to get that. How can I solv this. For more reference, you can check the image.

[image]

Check the code below:

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import Image from 'next/image'
import navbar from '/const/navbar'
import Button from '../button'
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Navbar() {
   const [activeClass, setActiveClass] = useState();
   return (
      <>
         <nav>
            <input id="nav-toggle" type="checkbox" />
            <div className="logo">
            <Link href="/">
            <Image className=" cursor-pointer h-8 opacity-90" src="/workforwin-logo.png" width={172} height={44} alt="Workforwin Logo" />
            </Link>
            </div>
               <ul className="links">
                  {/* Getting nav items */}
                  {navbar.data.map((items, i) => (
                     <li className='hover:text-indigo-600' key={i}><Link href={items.link}>{items.text}</Link></li>
                  ))}
                  {/* Account Button */}
                  <Button link="" data="Account" type="" />
               </ul>
            <label htmlFor="nav-toggle" className="icon-burger">
               <div className="line"></div>
               <div className="line"></div>
               <div className="line"></div>
            </label>
         </nav>
      </>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will assume that the first item in your nav is initially **active**.

we will set the state to it's default value which is **0**

```
   const [activeClass, setActiveClass] = useState(0);
```

In the nav items, we will check for each item if the index of that item is equal to the current state, if yes, display it's current color as blue 600.

**N.B.** `i` as the 2nd arugment in the map functions are 0 based and represents the index of the current element being processed in the array.

```
{navbar.data.map((items, i) => (
         <li className={activeClass === i ? "text-blue-600" : "hover:text-indigo-600" } 
          key={i} onClick={() => handleItemClick(i)} >
         <Link href={items.link}>
             {items.text}
         </Link>
         </li>
))}
```

An onClick handler that changes the state based on the clicked index

```
const handleItemClick = (idx) => {
// this will trigger a rerender
setActiveClass(idx)
}
```